Solving $y''(x)-2xy'(x)+y(x) = 0$ using power series
I'm solving $y''(x) -2xy'(x) +y(x) = 0$ using the power series ansatz $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ . Plugging in I get:
\begin{equation}
\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}\bigg)-2x\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}\bigg)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n = 0 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \big((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} -2na_n+a_n\big) = 0 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} -2na_n+a_n = 0 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a_{n+2} = \frac{2n-1}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n
\end{equation}
Now we set $a_0$ and $a_1$ as parameters, to observe a pattern:
\begin{align}
n\qquad & \\\\
0\qquad & a_2 = \frac{-1}{2 \cdot 1} a_0 &= \frac{a_0}{2!}\prod_{l=0}^{0}(4l-1) \\\\
1\qquad & a_3 = \frac{1}{3\cdot 2} a_1 &= \frac{a_1}{3!}\prod_{l=0}^{0}(4l+1) \\\\
2\qquad & a_4 = \frac{3}{4\cdot 3} a_2 = \frac{3}{4 \cdot 3} \frac{-1}{2\cdot 1} a_0 &= \frac{a_0}{4!} \prod_{l=0}^{1}(4l-1) \\\\
3\qquad & a_5 = \frac{5}{5\cdot 4} a_3 = \frac{5}{5\cdot 4}\frac{1}{3\cdot 2} a_1 &= \frac{a_1}{5!}\prod_{l=0}^{1}(4l+1) \\\\
4 \qquad & a_6 = \frac{7}{6\cdot 5} a_4 = \frac{7}{6\cdot 5}\frac{3}{4 \cdot 3} \frac{-1}{2\cdot 1} a_0 &= \frac{a_0}{6!} \prod_{l=0}^{2}(4l-1)\\\\
5 \qquad & a_7 = \frac{9}{7\cdot 6} a_5 = \frac{9}{7\cdot 6}\frac{5}{5\cdot 4}\frac{1}{3\cdot 2} a_1 &= \frac{a_1}{7!}\prod_{l=0}^{2}(4l+1) \\\\
6 \qquad & a_8 = \frac{11}{8\cdot 7} a_6 = \frac{11}{8\cdot 7}\frac{7}{6\cdot 5}\frac{3}{4 \cdot 3} \frac{-1}{2\cdot 1} a_0 &= \frac{a_0}{8!} \prod_{l=0}^{3}(4l-1)\\\\
7 \qquad & a_9 = \frac{13}{9\cdot 8} a_7 = \frac{13}{9 \cdot 8}\frac{9}{7\cdot 6}\frac{5}{5\cdot 4}\frac{1}{3\cdot 2} a_1 &= \frac{a_1}{9!}\prod_{l=0}^{3}(4l+1) \\\\
\cdots
\end{align}
So I now only need to plug these into $y(x)$. For that I split the sum into odd and even parts:
\begin{align}
y(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n \\\\&= \bigg( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k} x^{2k} \bigg) + \bigg( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k+1} x^{2k+1} \bigg) \\\\&= \bigg(a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{2k} x^{2k} \bigg) + \bigg(a_1x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{2k+1} x^{2k+1} \bigg) \\\\&= \bigg(a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k} \frac{a_0}{(k+2)!}\prod_{l=0}^{k}(4l-1)  \bigg) + \bigg(a_1x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k+1} \frac{a_1}{(k+2)!} \prod_{l=0}^{k}(4l+1) \bigg) \\\\&= a_0 \bigg(1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{(k+2)!}\prod_{l=0}^{k}(4l-1)  \bigg) + a_1 \bigg(x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(k+2)!} \prod_{l=0}^{k}(4l+1) \bigg) 
\end{align}

But now I tried to check the solution by plugging it back in the equation. But first I made following abbreviations:
\begin{equation}
\alpha_k = \frac{1}{(2+k)!}\prod_{l=0}^{k}(4l-1) \qquad\qquad \beta_k = \frac{1}{(2+k)!}\prod_{l=0}^{k}(4l+1)
\end{equation}
So we now have:
\begin{align}
y(x) &= a_0 \bigg(1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k} \alpha_k  \bigg) + a_1 \bigg(x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k+1} \beta_k \bigg) \\\\
y'(x) &= a_0 \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2k x^{2k-1} \alpha_k  \bigg) + a_1 \bigg(1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2k+1)x^{2k} \beta_k \bigg) \\\\
y''(x) &= a_0 \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2k(2k-1) x^{2k-2} \alpha_k  \bigg) + a_1 \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2k+1)2kx^{2k-1} \beta_k \bigg) 
\end{align}
I started with following term:
\begin{align}
2xy'(x)-y(x) &= a_0 \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 4kx^{2k} \alpha_k  \bigg) + a_1 \bigg(2x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2(2k+1)x^{2k+1} \beta_k \bigg) \\\\ & \quad- a_0 \bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k} \alpha_k  \bigg) - a_1 \bigg(x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k+1} \beta_k \bigg) \\\\ &= a_0 \bigg(-1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k}(4k-1) \alpha_k  \bigg) + a_1 \bigg(x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(4k+1)x^{2k+1}\beta_k\bigg) 
\end{align}
But this obviously doesn't equal $y''(x)$. Where did I go wrong?

Your formulas for $a_k$ are wrong. In the exploration of the values, they are right, but then you make the wrong generalization. They must be
$$
a_{2k} = \frac{a_0}{(2k)!}\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(4\ell-1) \quad \text{and} \quad a_{2k+1} = \frac{a_1}{(2k+1)!}\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(4\ell+1),
$$
but it seems that you wrote
$$
a_{2k} = \frac{a_0}{(k+2)!}\prod_{\ell=0}^{k}(4\ell-1) \quad \text{and} \quad a_{2k+1} = \frac{a_1}{(k+2)!}\prod_{\ell=0}^{k}(4\ell+1).
$$
ADDED: To give an answer to the question in your commentary, you computations are correct, you only need some additional computations: note that
$$
a_{2k}(4k-1)=a_{2k+2}(2k+2)(2k+1) \quad \text{and} \quad a_{2k+1}(4k+1)=a_{2k+3}(2k+3)(2k+2)
$$
(you can prove it by a direct calculation or by using the recurrence relation)so you obtain
$$
2xy'-y = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (a_{2j+2}(2j+2)(2j+1)x^{2j} + a_{2j+3}(2j+3)(2j+2)x^{2j+1}).
$$
Reindexing the sum by making $j=k-1$ we obtain
$$
2xy'-y = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{2k})(2k)(2k-1)x^{2k-2} + a_{2k+1}(2k+1)(2k)x^{2k-1}).
$$
The pressence of the factors $2k$ in the series make us possible to start the sum at $k=0$ (for in this case we are summing zero), and we obtain
$$
2xy'-y = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_{2k})(2k)(2k-1)x^{2k-2} + a_{2k+1}(2k+1)(2k)x^{2k-1}) = y''.
$$
$$

You are correct, but could something else be wrong too? I still get $2xy'(x)-y(x) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \Big(x^{2k}a_{2k} (4k-1) + a_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}(4k+1)\Big) \neq y''(x)$

@haifisch123 Your computations are now correct, you have to do a couple more calculations to obtain $y''$, I added some details to my answer.
